# Elementary set theory: is it true that $(A \cup B) \cup C = (A \cup C) \cup (B \cup C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Sorry for the childish question. I know that

$$
(A\cup B) \cap C = (A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C)
$$

and that when we have only unions or intersections the brackets don't really matter, so I guess what I'm really asking is are 
$$
A \cup B \cup C
$$
and 
$$
(A \cup B) \cup C = (A \cup C) \cup (B \cup C)
$$
one and the same?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, by idempotent/associative/commutative law:
\begin{align*}
A \cup B \cup C
&= (A \cup B) \cup C \\
&= (A \cup B) \cup (C \cup C) \\
&= A \cup (B \cup C) \cup C \\
&= A \cup (C \cup B) \cup C \\
&= (A \cup C) \cup (B \cup C) \\
\end{align*}